# Something's peeling off from around my rear wheel well. Is this clear coat failing?

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

It started off as an air bubble that I thought was something dried on there. When I foolishly tried scraping it off with my fingernail, a thin clear layer started to peel off and this is what it looks like right now.

The strange thing is that this layer seems to be on top of those sticker-like things you see on the leading edges (which I presume are there to protect against stone chips), so if it really is clear coat, then it would seem that it was sprayed over those sticker things.

The car's around 4 years old now and I do intend to keep it until it becomes too expensive to maintain. Should I get it fixed or not before it gets worse?

[image: Paint peeling]

Comment: Yes thats lacquer, have you had it from new? has it had any accident or stone-chip damage repaired int he area?

Comment: It looks like a repair of some kind. I would never expect UV damage at the bottom of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Given the vehicle's relatively young age and location of the orange peel, I'd say this is due to abrasion more than UV exposure.

If so, this issue should remain fairly localized. If it is an eyesore then it can be wet-sanded and polished, but it could easily come back if the source of the abrasion isn't eliminated.